# navigator.getUserMedia alternative API for iOS safari mobile browser?

Tags: html, camera, html5-video, mobile-safari, webrtc

I know with below code will capture a image from ios 6+ safari mobile browser

```
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">
```

Is there any other way of capturing a image from safari mobile browser using html5/JS?

Is there any alternative for WebRTC MediaStream API in iOS safari mobile browser?

Comment: Safari does not have webrtc support, so, no. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying achieve reading of live camera preview frames from safari browsers

Answer (score 2):

Safari does not support WebRTC yet.

http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/

To start with WebRTC on iOS, you may explore this demo https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios. It't not exactly the same as you're looking for. The demo app achieves video chat. But it should be trivial to get image

Comment: @JoeMiller "the essential parts of the answer" is "Safari does not support WebRTC yet."

Comment: @JoeMiller - Joe did include the essential parts of the link provided, 'Safari does not support WebRTC yet', and provided the link as the source of his claim. This is not a 'link-only answer'.